# How can i copy files from any usb stick to user's home directory using terminal command line?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, terminal, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I have a usb stick that contains the folders "theme" and "icons". I want to copy those 2 folders in the folder home/andrew/.config folder of my computer or any other computer. How can i do that using the terminal?

I am on a Linux Mint xfce system.

Comment: If it's just a one-time copy, running `cp -r src-dir dest-dir` should be sufficient. Are you looking for something more advanced?

Answer (score 0):

Given your username is Andrew or rather `andrew`, it will most likely be mounted under `/media/andrew/a_volume_name`. So first you need to get this full path. You can store it in a shell variable to make things easy:

```
ls /media/andrew
```

See or find the right entry in the output, and now save it in the source directory variable:

```
s_dir=/media/andrew/my_usb_drive
```

Of course replace `my_usb_drive` with the right name. Once you have this, enter this command:

```
cp -r "$s_dir"/theme "$s_dir"/icons /home/andrew/.config
```

Comment: Is there any wild card for the usb path? For example how can i copy my usb folders to a friend's computer if i dont know the name of his home directory?

Comment: Run `ls /home` ...

Comment: The usb mount point is variable. /media is deprecated in many modern OS. Run `mount` to find the mount point

Comment: `~` is a variable which directly references the current users home directory.

Comment: @Designer This is too broad to automate easily, though it may be done, as per the comments above.